# Uncaught TypeError: dialEl.mathquill is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate a formula editor into a custom plugin and I am encountering this problem (see attached file). Any solutions?

error

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue, have you found the solution?